# Hibernate Query Language (HQL) QueryException: could not resolve property: Transactions of: classes.Advicenote, how could I solve this? I am confused

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hql

[Herre is the enitity-relatiosnhip diagram of my database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUX4J.png)

**Advicenote** table's In_Or_Out variable indicates whether items are going out or coming in from the company, while **Transactions** has a flow variable, which actually the number or amount of items that comes in or goes out from the system. I want to query the actual quantity of the items in the inventory, by multiplying Advicenote.In_Or_Out and Transactions.Flow, then I would sum then and group them by the Items.Item_ID. **I would appreciate any help!**

Below you can see the HQL that I've written for this purpose and the error message that I recieve:

```
public List<ItemAndQuantity> getQuantity()
        {
        List<ItemAndQuantity> quantity = new ArrayList<ItemAndQuantity>();



            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join a.Transactions t join t.Items i group by i.itemId");
                quantity = query.list();
                transaction.commit();
            } 
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        finally {
             session.close();}
             return quantity;
        }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
>   could not resolve property: Transactions of: classes.Advicenote
>   [select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from classes.Advicenote a join
>   a.Transactions t join t.Items i group by i.itemId]    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:713)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
>     at stock.view.StockView.getQuantity(StockView.java:145)     at
>   stock.view.StockView.FillData(StockView.java:62)  at
>   stock.view.StockView.(StockView.java:38)    at
>   main.view.MainMenu.stockMenuItemActionPerformed(MainMenu.java:290)    at
>   main.view.MainMenu$FormListener.actionPerformed(MainMenu.java:240)    at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   Transactions of: classes.Advicenote [select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut)
>   from classes.Advicenote a join a.Transactions t join t.Items i group
>   by i.itemId]  at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:118)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:78)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:595)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704)
>     ... 44 more Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not
>   resolve property: Transactions of: classes.Advicenote     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:73)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1983)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:396)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:515)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:686)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:204)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:408)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3920)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3706)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
>     ... 50 more

At lastly here are the affected classes and xml mappings:
Advicenote

```
package classes;

        import java.util.Date;
        import java.util.Set;

        public class Advicenote  implements java.io.Serializable {


             private int advicenoteId;
             private Short inOrOut;
             private Date advicedate;
             private Partner partner;
             private Set<Transactions> transactions;

            public Advicenote() {
            }

            public Advicenote(int advicenoteId, Short inOrOut, Date advicedate, Partner partner, Set<Transactions> transactions) {
                this.advicenoteId = advicenoteId;
                this.inOrOut = inOrOut;
                this.advicedate = advicedate;
                this.partner = partner;
                this.transactions = transactions;
            }


            public int getAdvicenoteId() {
                return this.advicenoteId;
            }

            public void setAdvicenoteId(int advicenoteId) {
                this.advicenoteId = advicenoteId;
            }

            public Date getAdvicedate() {
                return advicedate;
            }

            public void setAdvicedate(Date advicedate) {
                this.advicedate = advicedate;
            }

                public Short getInOrOut() {
                return this.inOrOut;
            }

            public void setInOrOut(Short inOrOut) {
                this.inOrOut = inOrOut;
            }

            public Partner getPartner() {
                return partner;
            }

            public void setPartner(Partner partner) {
                this.partner = partner;
            }


            public Set<Transactions> getTransactions() {
                return transactions;
            }

            public void setTransactions(Set<Transactions> transactions) {
                this.transactions = transactions;
            }


        }
```

Advicenote XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Advicenote" table="ADVICENOTE" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="advicenoteId" type="int" column="ADVICENOTE_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="advicedate" type="date" column="ADVICE_DATE" length="10" />
        <property name="inOrOut" type="java.lang.Short" column="IN_OR_OUT" />
        <many-to-one 
            name="partner" class="classes.Partner"/>  
        <set name="transactions" table="TRANSACTIONS" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">       
            <key column="ADVICENOTE_ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="classes.Transactions"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Transactions class:

```
package classes;

public class Transactions  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int transactionsId;
     private int flow;
     private Integer netPrice;
     private Advicenote advicenote;
     private Items item;

    public Transactions() {
    }

    public Transactions(int transactionsId, int flow, Integer netPrice, Advicenote advicenote, Items item) {
        this.transactionsId = transactionsId;
        this.flow = flow;
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
        this.advicenote = advicenote;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public int getTransactionsId() {
        return this.transactionsId;
    }

    public void setTransactionsId(int transactionsId) {
        this.transactionsId = transactionsId;
    }

    public int getFlow() {
        return this.flow;
    }

    public void setFlow(int flow) {
        this.flow = flow;
    }

    public Integer getNetPrice() {
        return this.netPrice;
    }

    public void setNetPrice(Integer netPrice) {
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
    }

    public Advicenote getAdvicenote() {
        return advicenote;
    }

    public void setAdvicenote(Advicenote advicenote) {
        this.advicenote = advicenote;
    } 

    public Items getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Items item) {
        this.item = item;
    }


}
```

Transactions XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Transactions" table="TRANSACTIONS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="transactionsId" type="int" column="TRANSACTIONS_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="flow" type="int" column="FLOW" not-null="true" />
        <property name="netPrice" type="java.lang.Integer" column="NET_PRICE" />

        <many-to-one name="advicenote" class="classes.Advicenote"/>
        <many-to-one name="item" class="classes.Items" fetch="select" cascade="save-update" column="ITEM_ID" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Items

```
package classes;

public class Items  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int itemId;
     private String name;
     private Integer netPrice;
     private Integer vatRate;
     private Categories category;
     //has-a relationship


    public Items() {
    }

    public Items(int itemId, String name, Integer netPrice, Integer vatRate, Categories category) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.name = name;
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
        this.vatRate = vatRate;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return this.itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getNetPrice() {
        return this.netPrice;
    }

    public void setNetPrice(Integer netPrice) {
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
    }
    public Integer getVatRate() {
        return this.vatRate;
    }

    public void setVatRate(Integer vatRate) {
        this.vatRate = vatRate;
    }

    public Categories getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Categories category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


}
```

Items XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Items" table="ITEMS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="itemId" type="int" column="ITEM_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" length="100"/>
        <property name="netPrice" type="java.lang.Integer" column="NET_PRICE"/>
        <property name="vatRate" type="java.lang.Integer" column="VAT_RATE"/>
        <many-to-one name="category" class="classes.Categories" fetch="select" column="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Categories XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Categories" table="CATEGORIES" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="categoryId" type="int">
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="100" />
        </property>
     <set name="items" table="ITEMS" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="classes.Items" />
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join a.Transactions t join t.Items i group by i.itemId
```

should be:

```
select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join a.transactions t join t.item i group by i.itemId
```

(`transactions` in lowercase and `item` also in lowercase and without 's'). They refer to the fields, not the classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, however I get another exception: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [classes.Categories#1] - no Session`

Comment: @Fluellen do you have a mapping file for class `Categories`? (BTW, is Fluellen your real name?)

Comment: Nope, it's not, why'd you ask? :)
I edited my question to include the Categories mapping file

Comment: I'm curious... I see a possible issue with the fact that `Items` and `Categories` reference each other. Perhaps either `Items.category` or `Categories.items` should have `inverse="true"` and/or `lazy="true"`.

Comment: @Fluellen no, actually I think that the problem is that you're using the result of the query after having closed the session. Don't do that.

Comment: But I assign it to  `List<ItemAndQuantity> quantity = new ArrayList<ItemAndQuantity>()`
Which looks like this: `public class ItemAndQuantity{
        private int ID;
        private int Quantity;

        public ItemAndQuantity(int ID, int Quantity) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
        } //getters and setters`

Comment: @Fluellen first, that's useless because you're doing `quantity = query.list();` afterwards, second, some objects are lazily loaded, so it's not enough to do a copy of the list.

Comment: Wow, I just started to learn ORM and relational database systems, I am currently working on this...this is supposed to be a basic inventory management software, would you mind taking a look at it? From your response time I can tell you have some experience in this topic :D So in this why is it useless to quantity = query.list(), and lazy loaded could be just turned to eager, isn't it?

Comment: @Fluellen You're initialising variable `quantity` with a new array that you never use, but override with `quantity = query.list();`. You could have instead filled it with the query result: `quantity.addAll(query.list());`. But again, that's not enough: the objects cannot be lazily loaded.

Comment: Oh I see, I think my whole application is filled with little mistakes like that :(

Comment: What is exactly the difference between `quantity = query.list();` and `quantity.addAll(query.list());`

Comment: @Fluellen the former assigns a reference to the list returned by `query.list()`; the latter copies the elements of that list into the list that the variable is already referencing (in this case, the list created at initialisation).

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with "a.Transactions"
Also Remove t.Items
Use this:-

```
select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join Transactions t join Items i group by i.itemId
```

Comment: Didn't solve it unfortunately :(

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Items of: classes.Transactions [select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from classes.Advicenote a join classes.Transactions t join t.Items i group by i.itemId]`

Comment: You are still using t.Items check my query again

Comment: I swear I ctrl+c ctrtl+v-d that query...but still no luck, when I use this I get another exception as such: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement``java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "inner" at line 1, column 143.`

Comment: your comment is still showing "join t.Items" in my query its only Items